# How can I disable or fix php-module which prevents compilation of PHP 5.6.24 from sources?

Tags: php, compilation, opcache

Compiling PHP **v.5.6.24** on Debian 8.5 x64 fails with the following error.

How can I fix this problem with **opcache** module or how to disable it in PHP "autoconf" before compilation?

> make all
>   /bin/bash /home/bob/A_php5/php-src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/bob/A_php5/php-src/include -I/home/bob/A_php5/php-src/main -I/home/bob/A_php5/php-src -I/home/bob/A_php5/php-src/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/bob/A_php5/php-src/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/home/bob/A_php5/php-src/TSRM -I/home/bob/A_php5/php-src/Zend    -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -DZEND_SIGNALS    -o ext/opcache/opcache.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /home/bob/A_php5/php-src/modules  ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_blacklist.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_debug.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_hash.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.lo ext/opcache/zend_persist.lo ext/opcache/zend_persist_calc.lo ext/opcache/zend_file_cache.lo ext/opcache/zend_shared_alloc.lo ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_util_funcs.lo ext/opcache/shared_alloc_shm.lo ext/opcache/shared_alloc_mmap.lo ext/opcache/shared_alloc_posix.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass1_5.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass2.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/optimize_func_calls.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/block_pass.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/optimize_temp_vars_5.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/nop_removal.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/compact_literals.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_cfg.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_dfg.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/dfa_pass.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_ssa.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_inference.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_func_info.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_call_graph.lo ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_dump.lo
>   Reloading web server: apache2 failed!
>   Apache2 is not running ... (warning).
>   Makefile:870: recipe for target 'ext/opcache/opcache.la' failed
>   make: *** [ext/opcache/opcache.la] Error 1